# Logged in cookie for Laconica doesn't work

Tags: login, laconica

When a user checks the "Remember me" check box at login they still have to log back in on the next visit, no matter how soon after that next visit is. It seems that the cookie isn't set correctly. Where and how can I verify this?

In config.php the following lines are set:

```
$config['site']['path'] = '/';
$config['site']['server'] = 'localtwit';
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/'. $config['site']['path'] .'/');
```

The cookie looks like this (somewhat obscured) when I check it in Webdeveloper:

```
Name    PHPSESSID
Value   061b8533dd208c9.................
Host    localtwit
Path    ///
Secure  No
Expires At End Of Session
```

I have a problem with the path having too many slashes in it, and that shows up in the cookie. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tool like WebDeveloper in Firefox to make sure the cookie is being set.

Comment: I added some cookie information to the question.

Comment: Based on your cookie info, it looks like you should have:

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');

You can also just not change the cookie parameters. You only need to change them if you've got more than one PHP program installed on the same server, and you don't want their session cookies to interfere with each other.